# Could not run nodejs on my public ip address

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, expo

Hi guys i have a basic code of nodejs like

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var createError = require("http-errors");
require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();

//ROUTES//
const userRoutes = require("./routes/UserRoutes");

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/", (req, res, next) => res.send("hello"));
app.use("/api", userRoutes);

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGOURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("connected and running"));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createError(404, "Not found"));
});
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("in error middleware");
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send({
    status: err.status || 500,
    message: err.message,
  });
});
app.listen(4000,() =>
  console.log(`listening on 4000`)
);
```

So as of now i am running on port=4000 so can access it via

`http://localhost:4000`

but i plan to use this server for my react native app using expo client app by which i am running my app on my mobile phone
I see that i cant get access via localhost so in client side i tried to access it via

`http://<my-public-ip>:4000`

but it doesn't get any response back only

`http://127.0.0.1:4000/`

but this works only in my pc and it's obvious , how do i access the local server through my mobile which is running my app ?

Comment: Are you running this on some external dedicated server or your home computer?  Have you configured port forwarding?  You are likely being firewalled.

Comment: home computer mate....whats port forwarding ?

Comment: You need to look into port forwarding and forward port 4000 from your PC. This can be done in your router settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to acces it from your local home network or from the internet ?

If it's from local network, juste use the local ip address of your pc (it probably starts with 192.168.XX.XX), you can find it with `ipconfig` on Windows CMD or `ip addr` on a Linux shell.

If it's from WAN (internet) you need to configure port forwarding in the firwall of your router, this mean "translate `<my-public-ip>:4000` into `<local-pc-ip>:4000` (found just like before)".
(You can find infos on the web by searching you the type/brand of your router to do it)